# Getting other metadata in ItemRequestForm in DSpace 6x

Tags: dspace

Clicking a restricted bitstream in DSpace will display a request form. The form displays the title of the item by default. In version 5x, I managed to get to display other metadata instead of title (eg citation).

The code I used to display:

```
    Metadatum[] titleDC = item.getMetadata("dc", "title", null, Item.ANY);
    Metadatum[] citationDC = item.getMetadata("dc", "identifier", "citation", Item.ANY);
    String document = "";
    if (citationDC != null && citationDC.length > 0) {
        document = citationDC[0].value;
    } else {
        if (titleDC != null && titleDC.length > 0)
            document = titleDC[0].value;
    }
    itemRequest.addPara(document);
```

I cannot use this code in version 6x because of major changes in the source code. Below is the default code in DSpace 6x to display the item's title:

```
String titleDC = item.getName();
if (titleDC != null && titleDC.length() > 0)
    itemRequest.addPara(titleDC);
```

It seems there is no `item.getMetadata` in version 6. My question is how to translate the version 5x code

```
Metadatum[] citationDC = item.getMetadata("dc", "identifier", "citation", Item.ANY);
```

into version 6?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking around in the DSpace 6x code, I managed to get other metadata to display (eg *dc.identifier.citation*) instead of item title in `ItemRequestForm.java`. Add to import `import org.dspace.content.service.ItemService;`

```
private final transient ItemService itemService
    = ContentServiceFactory.getInstance().getItemService();
```

**To display *dc.identifier.citation***

```
String citationDC = itemService.getMetadataFirstValue(item, "dc", "identifier", "citation", Item.ANY);
String titleDC = item.getName();
String document = "";
    if (citationDC != null && citationDC.length() > 0) {
        document = citationDC;
    } else {
        if (titleDC != null && titleDC.length() > 0)
        document = titleDC;
    }

itemRequest.addPara(document);
```

I added a test as a fallback in case *dc.identifier.citation* does not exist.