# Getting a modified version of ItemRequestForm.java to work in DSpace version 6x

Tags: java, dspace

I have a modified version of `ItemRequestForm.java` that previously worked in version 5x. In `item-view.xsl`, I created a link that when clicked, will redirect the user to this modified form. The URL pattern of this link is `http://example.com/documentdelivery/123456789/1234`. When I upgrade my DSpace version to 6x, I have difficulty in making it work. Due to major code refactoring between versions 5 and 6, I find it hard to migrate my code to the latest version.

**Below is part of the code that worked in version 5x** ([DocumentDeliveryForm.java](https://github.com/eulereadgbe/DSpace/blob/2cc09aa813ae1b7c84895d7d2322df8a9997e298/dspace/modules/xmlui/src/main/java/org/dspace/app/xmlui/aspect/artifactbrowser/DocumentDeliveryForm.java))

The code is mostly based on this answer: [How can I get the title of the referring page (item) from a modified version of feedback page in DSpace?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26120316/1919069)

```
    String handle=parameters.getParameter("handle","unknown");
    DSpaceObject dso = HandleManager.resolveToObject(context, handle);
    if (!(dso instanceof Item)) {
        return;
    }
    Request request = ObjectModelHelper.getRequest(objectModel);
    boolean firstVisit=Boolean.valueOf(request.getParameter("firstVisit"));

    Item item = (Item) dso;

    // Build the item viewer division.
    Division documentdelivery = body.addInteractiveDivision("DocumentDelivery-form",
            contextPath+"/documentdelivery/"+parameters.getParameter("handle","unknown"),Division.METHOD_POST,"primary");
```

When I upgrade to version 6, I found out that `DSpaceObject dso = HandleManager.resolveToObject(context, handle)` no longer worked, so I replaced it with `DSpaceObject dso = handleService.resolveToObject(context, handle)`.

**Below is my attempt to migrate my 5x code to 6x** (Result: java.lang.NullPointerException)

```
    String handle=parameters.getParameter("handle","unknown");
    DSpaceObject dso = handleService.resolveToObject(context, handle);
    if (!(dso instanceof Item)) {
        return;
    }
    Request request = ObjectModelHelper.getRequest(objectModel);
    Item item = (Item) dso;

    // Build the item viewer division.
    Division documentdelivery = body.addInteractiveDivision("DocumentDelivery-form",
            request.getRequestURI() + "/documentdelivery/" + item.getHandle(), Division.METHOD_POST,"primary");
```

**Below is another attempt that resulted in Handle is null**

```
    Request request = ObjectModelHelper.getRequest(objectModel);
    String handle = request.getParameter("handle");
    DSpaceObject dso = handleService.resolveToObject(context, handle);
    if (!(dso instanceof Item)) {
        return;
    }
    boolean firstVisit=Boolean.valueOf(request.getParameter("firstVisit"));

    Item item = (Item) dso;

    // Build the item viewer division.
    Division documentdelivery = body.addInteractiveDivision("DocumentDelivery-form",
            contextPath+"/documentdelivery/"+parameters.getParameter("handle","unknown"),Division.METHOD_POST,"primary");
```

Looking at the java stacktrace, it is pointing to this line of code: `DSpaceObject dso = handleService.resolveToObject(context, handle)`. It seems that the value for **handle** is not being loaded.

What part of my code should I modify so that I can successfully redirect users to `http://example.com/documentdelivery/123456789/1234` from `http://example.com/handle/123456789/1234`?

Which construction of item viewer division is correct?

```
    Division documentdelivery = body.addInteractiveDivision("DocumentDelivery-form",
            request.getRequestURI() + "/documentdelivery/" + item.getHandle(), Division.METHOD_POST,"primary");
```

**OR**

```
    Division documentdelivery = body.addInteractiveDivision("DocumentDelivery-form",
            contextPath+"/documentdelivery/"+parameters.getParameter("handle","unknown"),Division.METHOD_POST,"primary");
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I managed to get it to work. I also displayed other metadata fields based on my previous post here: [Getting other metadata in ItemRequestForm in DSpace 6x](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61556258/1919069)

```
public void addBody(Body body) throws SAXException, WingException,
        UIException, SQLException, IOException, AuthorizeException
{
    Request request = ObjectModelHelper.getRequest(objectModel);

    // Build the item viewer division.
    Division documentdelivery = body.addInteractiveDivision("documentdelivery-form",
            contextPath+"/documentdelivery/"+parameters.getParameter("handle", "unknown"),Division.METHOD_POST,"primary");

    documentdelivery.setHead(T_head);

    String handle = parameters.getParameter("handle","unknown");
    DSpaceObject dso = handleService.resolveToObject(context, handle);
    Item item = (Item) dso;

    String citationDC = itemService.getMetadataFirstValue(item, "dc", "identifier", "citation", org.dspace.content.Item.ANY);
    String titleDC = item.getName();
    String title = "";
    if (citationDC != null && citationDC.length() > 0) {
        title = citationDC;
    } else {
        if (titleDC != null && titleDC.length() > 0)
            title = titleDC;
    }
    documentdelivery.addPara(title);
```

I also added the necessary imports:

```
import org.dspace.content.service.ItemService;
import org.dspace.handle.factory.HandleServiceFactory;
import org.dspace.handle.service.HandleService;
```

And also I added these:

```
    private final transient ItemService itemService = ContentServiceFactory.getInstance().getItemService();
    private final transient HandleService handleService = HandleServiceFactory.getInstance().getHandleService();
```